# javafx application, cannot interact with window

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

i am making a *simple* library application and while building the login screen i have the following 3 problems.

[the login window][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB7jJ.png

problem 1:
while launching the application i cannot type in the textfields, but i **can** highlight them.

problem 2:
the prompttext given for my 2 textfields is not showing (should be Username and Password)

problem 3:
my button is not clickable while it is not disabled in properties

here is my current code.

**the view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="489.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label text="Login" textFill="#a49f9f">
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="100.0" left="100.0" right="100.0" top="100.0" />
         </padding>
         <font>
            <Font size="38.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="LoginBtn" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="133.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0078D7; -fx-background-radius: 0;" text="Login" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="50.0" left="100.0" right="50.0" top="50.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Button>
      <TextField fx:id="usernametxt" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="248.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="274.0" promptText="Username" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="50.0" left="50.0" right="50.0" top="50.0" />
         </padding>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="50.0" left="100.0" right="50.0" top="50.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <TextField fx:id="passwordtxt" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="148.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="274.0" promptText="Password" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.vgrow="NEVER">
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="50.0" left="50.0" right="50.0" top="50.0" />
         </padding>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="50.0" left="100.0" right="50.0" top="50.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </TextField>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

**Controller:**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class HelloController {

    @FXML
    private Button LoginBtn; // yes this is the same as my fxid


    public void onLoginBtnClick() {
        LoginBtn.setDisable(true);


    }
}
```

finally the application itself

```
package com.inholland.nl.eindopdracht;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 489, 400);
        stage.setTitle("Login");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems 1 and 2 are caused by the excessive padding in the text fields, which doesn't allow any space to type any text. Remove the padding.

Problem 3 doesn't appear for me. Note that you have not specified a controller in the FXML, so no code is actually executed. Add `fx:controller="com.inholland.nl.eindopdracht.HelloController"` to the `GridPane` element.

Note also you should not specify layout coordinates when using a layout pane.

The following FXML works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="489.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.inholland.nl.eindopdracht.HelloController">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <Label text="Login" textFill="#a49f9f">
            <padding>
                <Insets bottom="100.0" left="100.0" right="100.0" top="100.0" />
            </padding>
            <font>
                <Font size="38.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Button fx:id="LoginBtn" onAction="#onLoginBtnClick" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="133.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0078D7; -fx-background-radius: 0;" text="Login" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
            <GridPane.margin>
                <Insets bottom="50.0" left="100.0" right="50.0" top="50.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
        </Button>
        <TextField fx:id="usernametxt" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="274.0" promptText="Username" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            <GridPane.margin>
                <Insets bottom="50.0" left="100.0" right="50.0" top="50.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
            <font>
                <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
            </font>
        </TextField>
        <TextField fx:id="passwordtxt" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="274.0" promptText="Password" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.vgrow="NEVER">
            <GridPane.margin>
                <Insets bottom="50.0" left="100.0" right="50.0" top="50.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
        </TextField>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```